# How do I "reopen" a very old question with a poor/outdated answer?

Tags: support, questions

I'm looking for a better answer to this very old question: [How can you write queries in a Google spreadsheet so that the columns are kept up to date?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33840/how-can-you-write-queries-in-a-google-spreadsheet-so-that-the-columns-are-kept-u)

How do I get new attention on it to farm better responses? I've done my own research and can't find a better way, nor can I find novel answers to questions that are similar enough.

I just feel like this question has a better answer than the one accepted. Do I create a new, duplicate question asking for answers filtered more specifically to my use case? (Probably bad to create dupes.) Do I post a comment on that old question to bump it? Do I just accept that answer as canon since nobody has contributed a new one in several years?

Comment: Why do you feel that the related question has a better answer? What do you don't like of the accepted answer?

Comment: Reasons I don't like the answer (all obviously just my opinion): Adding "parameter" cells that are referenced in lots of places makes it larger [and potentially slower](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89416/which-factor-will-give-most-speedup-to-every-update-to-a-large-google-spreadshee?rq=1). Updating the list of cell refs and the named range attached to them is prone to developer error. A note is required to teach devs (me) why I put this column of letters in the sheet and how it's used; no such "comment" can be left in the formulas, though. An ignorant edit will break them.

Comment: Take a look http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87913/88163

Comment: I just posted an answer to the related question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97545/88163

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to garner attention to an old question, including one that needs a refresh on the answers, is to post [a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). There's even an option for a bounty reason to 'get a more up-to-date answer' (paraphrased).

A bounty requires a minimum of 75 reputation points, so that option is not open to you at this time.

(For more information, see [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/21960))

You *could* edit the question (or one of the answers), which will cause the question to return to the front page. If you do that, though, be sure that it's a real, helpful, edit. Editing simply to bump a question is frowned upon (and could get your privileges curtailed if abused). But that doesn't mean it'll necessarily get any more attention.

*Don't* create a duplicate question, unless you can show that your question differs from the original in some significant way. Otherwise, it'll simply be closed as a duplicate of the original.

Comment: I've decided the question is interesting enough that I've decided to spend some of my reputation on a bounty. Don't expect, though, that asking someone to put on a bounty for you is a viable path.